# Access denied when making api calls to s3 bucket with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using Node.js, I'm making an api that makes calls to my s3 bucket on AWS. When I try to make use `putObject` method, i receive this error:

```
  message: 'Access Denied',
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2018-07-27T17:08:29.555Z,
  ... etc
```

}
I have a config and credentials file in `C:/User/{User}/.aws/` directory

config file:

```
[default]
region=us-east-2
output=json
```

credentials file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I created policies for both IAM user and Bucket. Here's my IAM user inline policy:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:GetObject"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

And my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1488494182833",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::134100338998:user/Test-User"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::admin-blog-assets"
        }
    ]
}
```

And finally, my api

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    s3 = new AWS.S3('admin-blog-assets');

...

  var params = {
  Bucket: 'admin-blog-assets',
  Key: file.filename,
  Body: fileData,
  ACL:'public-read'
  };
  s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
      if (perr) {
          console.log("Error uploading image: ", perr);                                                
      } else {
          console.log("uploading image successfully");                       
      }                      
  });
```

I've been banging my head on this for hours, can anyone help?

Comment: `"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::admin-blog-assets",  "arn:aws:s3:::admin-blog-assets/*" ]`

Comment: Ty for this, I did need to update my policy. It works like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the source of the problem is related to how you are defining the `s3` object, as `s3 = new AWS.S3('admin-blog-assets');`

If you look at the example [used here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html#getting-started-nodejs-js-code), it has this line:

```
var bucketPromise = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'}).createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}).promise();
```

Where the argument passed to `AWS.S3` is an object containing that `apiVersion` field. But you are passing a string value.

The [S3 specific documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) overview section has more information:

> Sending a Request Using S3 var s3 = new AWS.S3();
>   s3.abortMultipartUpload(params, function (err, data) {   if (err)
>   console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred   else
>   console.log(data);           // successful response }); Locking the
>   API Version In order to ensure that the S3 object uses this specific
>   API, you can construct the object by passing the apiVersion option to
>   the constructor:
>
> ```
> var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'}); You can also set the
> ```
>
> API version globally in AWS.config.apiVersions using the s3 service
>   identifier:
>
> AWS.config.apiVersions = {   s3: '2006-03-01',   // other service API
>   versions };
>
> ```
> var s3 = new AWS.S3();
> ```

Comment: Ty for this! It works now, I just needed to include the apiVersion and update my policy

Answer (score 0):

Some of the permissions you were granting were bucket permissions and others were object permissions.  There are actions matching `s3:Get*` and `s3:Put*` that apply to both buckets and objects.

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"` is only the bucket itself, not the objects inside it.

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"` is only the objects in the bucket, and not the bucket itself.

You can write two policy statements, or you can combine the resources, like this:

```
"Resource": [ 
  "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
  "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*" 
]
```

**Important Security Consideration:** By using `s3:Put*` with both the bucket and object ARNs, your policy likely violates the principle of least privilege, because you have implicitly granted this user `s3:PutBucketPolicy` which allows these credentials to change the bucket policy.  There may be other, similar concerns.  You probably do not want to give these credentials that much control.

---

Credit to @PatNeedham for noticing a second issue that I overlooked, the `AWS.S3()` constructor expects an object as its first argument, not a string.